# My uploaded image doesn't save in the storage file

Tags: laravel, file, filesystems, storage, thumbnails

I've followed the steps of Laracasts, but it's not working.

When I submit the form it returns:

```
Done: storage/thumbnails/k0TF3NW6WvWWjHuEtZ0OW7TTRQbfSB6lvD1GJls3.png
```

But I couldn't find it anywhere. My storage/thumbnails is empty.

My Controller:

```
  $path = request()->file('thumbnail')->store('storage/thumbnails');
  return 'Done: ' . $path;
```

My filesystems.php

```
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'public'),


        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

How can I find the uploaded file? Thanks!

Comment: Please tell me your directory patch from root 
I mean  storage/thumbnails

Comment: Did you use try-catch block?
It will help you to debug any exception on your controller method.

Comment: My dump file->thumbnail

Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#295 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "user (1).png"
  -mimeType: "image/png"
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "/tmp"
  filename: "phpj518oc"
  basename: "phpj518oc"
  pathname: "/tmp/phpj518oc"
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/tmp/phpj518oc"
  aTime: 2022-10-12 11:34:59
  mTime: 2022-10-12 11:34:59
  cTime: 2022-10-12 11:34:59
  inode: 6454
  size: 1628
  perms: 0100600
  owner: 1000
  group: 1000
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
}

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this code please.

```
$file = $request->file('thumbnail');
$file_name = uniqid()."_".time().'.'.$file->extension();
$file_location = '/thumbnail/';
$file-> move(storage_path($file_location), $file_name);
```

I hope the code helps you. Have a good one :)

Comment: By posting the form with these code, he doesn't post the form and delete the file. 

Visual studio code don't accept these code: $file = $request->file('thumbnail');

I've changed to:  $file = request()->file('thumbnail');

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Just add this parameter to your function : Request $request 

Like this :
public function MyFunction(Request $request){...}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "php artisan storage:link" command?

Comment: ... link already exists.
The links have been created.

But thanks for your help!

Comment: This reads more like a comment than an answer to me. One of the primary purposes of the question's comment section is to ask for clarification or more details from the asker.